# Refresh a table after removing a row in the binded array?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor

i'm trying to create a table for user management on my website. The table work perfectly, and now i'm trying to add buttons on each rows to give possibility to delete rows.

But, when i click on a button in a row, nothing happens. With the debugger, i can see that the row has been deleted of the array binded to the table but the table always show it.

The HTML :

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users |  filter : usersProperties : searchString; let id = index">
          <th class='UId'>{{user.uId}}</th>
          <th class='Username' contenteditable="true" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'name', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'name', $event)">{{user.userName}}</th>
          <th class='Prenom' contenteditable="true" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'name', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'name', $event)">{{user.uFirstName}}</th>
          <th class='Nom' contenteditable="true" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'name', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'name', $event)">{{user.uLastName}}</th>
          <th class='Admin' contenteditable="true" (keyup)="changeValue(id, 'name', $event)" (blur)="updateList(id, 'name', $event)">{{user.uIsAdmin}}</th>
          <th class='suppr'>
            <span class="table-remove">    
              <!-- Her it's the butto for delete the row -->
              <button type="button" class='btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0 shadow-sm' (click)="remove(id)">Remove</button>
            </span>
          </th>
        </tr>
```

The TypeScript :

```
remove(id: number) {
    this.deleteddrow = []
    if(this.users[id] != null){
      this.deleteddrow.push(this.users[id]);
      this.users.splice(id, 1);
    }
  }
```

(i keep the deleted rows in an array to update my Database)

EDIT : 
The users object use a model :

```
export class UserModel{
    uId : Number
    userName: string
    uFirstName: string
    uLastName: string
    uPassword: string
    uIsAdmin: boolean
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need pipe transform() to fire. Try swapping the following, the reassigning should call it.

```
this.users.splice(id, 1);
```

for the following. you probably shouldnt pass index as id but the below should help.

```
this.users = this.users.filter(data => data !== this.users[id]);
```

Its the same as doing this, but as mentioned should trigger `transform()`.

```js
let x = [1, 2, 3];

x = x.filter(data => data !== x[1]);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Your answer will probably solve the issue but the explanation is not correct. A change detection will fire on the button click not when you give a new reference to Object. Since the pipe the user is using, is probably a `pure` pipe so the `transform()` will not run unless a new reference is detected. Another solution could had been to make it an impure pipe. Giving a new reference is a much better option I believe.

Comment: you keep me on my toes, I thought a new reference to Object would make change detection run.

Comment: row.id ins't a known element.. My array use a model, users: UserModel[];

Comment: and what does UserModel look like>?

Comment: I modified my post. I have an id in the model but it's not the same that the index of the array